# How to retrieve the previous Non-Null value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to convert the data in **CustomerAudit** table into the format depicted in **CustomerHistory**. 
CustomerAudit logs changes (add,edit,delete) to Customer properties. (Name, Address, Phone) . CustomerHistory is a snapshot table that lists customer's properties at a given date in time as they change.

Table: **CustomerAudit**

```
Id  Entity   EntityId  Field    OldValue      NewValue     Type   AuditDate  
1   Customer 1         Name     NULL          Joe          Add    2016-01-01
2   Customer 1         Phone    NULL          567-54-3332  Add    2016-01-01
3   Customer 1         Address  NULL          456 Centre   Add    2016-01-01
4   Customer 1         Address  456 Centre    123 Main     Edit   2016-01-02
5   Customer 1         Phone    567-54-3332   843-43-1230  Edit   2016-01-03
6   Customer 1         Phone    843-43-1230   NULL         Delete 2016-01-04
```

Table: **CustomerHistory**

```
EntityId   Name   Address      Phone         AuditDate
1          Joe    456 Centre   567-54-3332   2016-01-01
1          Joe    123 Main     567-54-3332   2016-01-02
1          Joe    123 Main     843-43-1230   2016-01-03
1          Joe    123 Main     NULL          2016-01-04
```

I have used CROSS APPLY which performed OK with 3 columns but very poorly with 30. I am using SQL Server 2012. I'd appreciate any kind of help to come up with a reasonably performing solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data changed by using conditional aggregation or pivot:

```
select entityid, auditdate,
       max(case when field = 'Name' then newvalue end) as name,
       max(case when field = 'Address' then newvalue end) as address,
       max(case when field = 'Phone' then newvalue end) as phone
from CustomerAudit
group by entityid, auditdate;
```

Then you want to fill in the previous values for `NULL`s:

If SQL Server implemented the `IGNORE NULLS` option on `LAG()`, then this would be easy:

```
with ea as (
      select entityid, auditdate,
             max(case when field = 'Name' then newvalue end) as name,
             max(case when field = 'Address' then newvalue end) as address,
             max(case when field = 'Phone' then newvalue end) as phone
      from CustomerAudit
      group by entityid, auditdate
     )
select entityid, auditdate,
       coalesce(name, lag(name ignore nulls) over (partition by entityid order by auditdate) as name,
       . . .
from ea;
```

But life is not so easy.  You have already tried the `outer apply` approach.  Here are some other methods

One brute force way just looks at different lag amounts and looks like this:

```
select entityid, auditdate,
       coalesce(name,
                lag(name, 1) over (partition by entityid order by auditdate),
                lag(name, 2) over (partition by entityid order by auditdate),
                lag(name, 3) over (partition by entityid order by auditdate),
                lag(name, 4) over (partition by entityid order by auditdate)
               ) as name
       . . .
from ea;
```

Of course, this version assumes that the values are in the last five rows.

Another crude way uses string manipulation:

```
select entityid, auditdate,
       coalesce(name,
                substring(max(left('00000000' + cast(id as varchar(8)), 8) + name) over (partition by entityid order by auditdate), 9, 100)
               ) as name
       . . .
from ea;
```

This is trickier for non-string data types.

Another method uses repeated `join`s:

```
select entityid, auditdate,
       max(case when name is not null then id end) over (partition by entityid order by auditdate) as nameid,
       . . .
```

Then, you need to `join` back to the original table to get the actual `name` value.  That should be fast because the `join` presumably uses an indexed column.  But the query is a wee bit more complicated.

```
LAG(address IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY EntityId ORDER BY Id)
```

Alas, it doesn't.  You can try: